# How to change the elements in an array in the process using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am making a program where I can fix the sequence of a list, the sequence is to be followed with a difference of 2. In this program if the difference is less than 2 I need to replace/change a certain number. Well, I have done most of the part but the problem is I can't replace it properly, and since I can't change the number in the process my output also comes out wrong.

```
list_1 = [1,2,5]
for i in range(1, len(list_1)):
    htl = list_1[i]-list_1[i-1]
    if not htl == 2:
       list_1[i-1] += 2
       print(list_1[i-1])
```

The output is:

```
3
4
```

But it's wrong, the correct ouput is:

```
3
```

Because I only need to change the number 2 to 3 to make it a correct sequence.

What I am doing in my code is that, I am subtracting backwards to spot the differences. If there is a difference, I am trying to add 2 to number it is being subtracted from, and then change the number that is being subtracted. But in my program I am having problem in replacing. For example(the subtraction starts from index 1 - index 0, index 2 - index 1 and it goes on): 2-1 = 1 so it's not clearly following the sequence, and I am trying to replace the 2 in 'list_1' with 3(by adding 2 to the number that index 1 is being subtracted from). I can't replace the number and since I can't replace that,the next output comes that shouldn't be there because only one change is needed.

My way may be really tangled up, but it was the best I could think of, if there is a faster way I would really appreciate the help. But otherwise I did like to fix my Code, where the general idea is to follow the sequence of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribution is wrong:

```
list_1 = [1,2,5]

for i in range(1, len(list_1)):
    htl = list_1[i]-list_1[i-1]
    if htl != 2:
       list_1[i] = list_1[i-1] + 2

print (list_1)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5]
```

But in the end, what you want is simply a sequence starting at an initial point and with a step of 2 and with a certain number of points

```
start = 1
points = 3
stop = points * 2 + start
list_1 = list(range(start, stop, 2))
```

Output:

```
Out[11]: [1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your explanation, you wish to convert

`list_1 = [1,2,5]` to `list_1 = [1,3,5]`

The line which is not giving the desired result is:

`list_1[i-1] += 2`

The first time the for loop iterates, it generates `list_1 = [3,2,5]`.

The second time it iterates, it generates `list_1 = [3,4,5]`.

Change the line:

`list_1[i-1] += 2`

to:

`list_1[i] = list_1[i-1] + 2`

*Update:*

You said if the difference is less than 2, you wish to make the change.

Consider changing the `if not htl ==2:` condition to `if htl < 2`.  This will then catch the situation where you have two consecutive elements which are equal.  It also reads better.

*Update 2:*

In order to catch an error where your list has only zero or one elements, I recommend you place a condition before the loop.  `if len(list_1) > 1:` would be a good place to start, otherwise the indexing will raise an IndexError.

Answer (score 0):

Less than 2?
I also think you were changing the -1 list value rather than the current index.

This should work?

```
list_1 = [1,2,5,6,7,8,15]
for i in range(1, len(list_1)):
    htl = list_1[i]-list_1[i-1]
    if htl < 2:
       list_1[i] =list_1[i-1]+2
       print(list_1[i-1])
print(list_1)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure to have totally understand what you want to do but first, to fixe you output probleme change :

> list_1[i-1] += 2

by

> list_1[i-1] += 2

and put your print outside of the for like that :

```
for i in range(1, len(list_1)):
    htl = list_1[i]-list_1[i-1]
    if not htl == 2:


   list_1[i-1] += 1
   print(list_1[i-1])
print(list_1[i-1])
```

Hope that can help you.

Comment: Your answer has a few problems - your suggestion to change a given line recommends changing it to the same thing (you missed the [i-1] to [i] in it).  Also, your code-block formatting has gone awry and doesn't solve OPs issue. All the best

Comment: Thank for your comment !